# Is it possible to control your character's movement with the analog stick?

Tags: harvest-moon-back-to-nature

I recently purchased Harvest Moon: Back To Nature on the PSN Store, however it appears as if I can only control my character's movement with the D-Pad, but I would greatly prefer to use the analog stick.

Is there any way to control my movement with the analog stick instead of the D-Pad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, via the menu brought up by pressing the Home button. Once inside this menu, do the following:

> **controller settings > switch analog mode > analog mode`**

Setting this to analog mode will enable the analog stick. I'm uncertain what digital mode does, and the [PS3 manual](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/game/2settings.html) isn't that helpful either. The only thing I can gather is that certain games only support one of the two modes, but doesn't offer any insight on what these two modes are.

Comment: The _Analog Mode_ setting is identical to pressing the _Analog_ button on the DualShock controllers. This switches the analog stick between reporting analog events for games that support them, and reporting the same events as the directional pad for games made before the DualShock.